# Passing conditional parameters from dotnet to postgres function thorwing 42883: Function not found error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have create function in postgres with around 18 parameters. Some of them paramters are not mandatory, hence while creating paramters from dotnet side, I am skipping them.

```
cmd.CommandText = "MyFunction";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_No", No));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Id", Id));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Status", Status));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Name", Name));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_User", User));
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Res)) {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Res", Res));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Super)) {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Super", Super));
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Days", Days));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Pit", Pit));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Types", Types));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Description", Description));
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Possible)) {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Possible", Possible));
            }
            if (Secondary != 0) {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Secondary", Secondary));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SecondaryRes)) {
               cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_SecondaryRes", SecondaryRes));
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Overall", Overall));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_Date", Date));
            if (TargetDate != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_TargetDate", TargetDate));
            }
            if (CompleteTargetDate != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_CompleteTargetDate", CompleteTargetDate));
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter("ip_CreatedBy", CreatedBy));
            return ExecuteNonQuery(cmd) > 0;
```

In my function I have added default values, like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MyFunction("ip_No" integer, "ip_Id" text, "ip_Status" integer, "ip_Name" text, "ip_User" text, "ip_Res" text default null,"ip_Super" text default null,"ip_Days" integer default 0,"ip_Pit" text default null,"ip_Types" integer default null,"ip_Description" text default null,"ip_Possible" text default null,"ip_Secondary" integer default null,"ip_SecondaryRes" text default null,"ip_Overall" integer default null,"ip_Date" timestamp without time zone default null,"ip_TargetDate" timestamp without time zone default null,"ip_CompleteTargetDate" timestamp without time zone default null,"ip_CreatedBy" text default null)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $$
BEGIN
```

Now When I try to run this I am getting the following error:

```
42883: function does not exists
```

is there any way I can acheive this without error?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks strange. Do you mean your function called successfully when you are not using conditional parameters?

Comment: @BorisR Yes, If I pass all parameters from c#, it works

Answer (score 1):

if you create function on PostgreSQL that is like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(p1 text, p2 text, p3 boolean)
```

When you call this function then you must put all parameters. If some of them parameters are not mandatory, you can write `null` value. But all parameters must write.

```
select * from test('test', 'test1', null);
```

In PostgreSQL you can create functions with same names and difference parameters. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(p1 text, p2 text, p3 boolean);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(p1 text, p2 text);
```

In this case you can call your function without parameter p3, example:

```
select * from test('test', 'test1', false);
--OR
select * from test('test', 'test1');
```

Next way you can create functions in PostgreSQL for default parameters, example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(p1 text, p2 text, p3 boolean default false);
```

In this case too you can call your function without parameter p3 too, inside the function value of p3 parameter will be default false:

```
select * from test('test', 'test1', true);
--OR
select * from test('test', 'test1');
```